# Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform Flutter Firebase Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to show a data string from firebase firestore in my flutter app. This should be an info text. I want that this text gets realtime updated. My problem is with this code that i'm getting this error:

StateError (Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform)

I've searched trough the entire internet but i haven't found any solutions for this... i hope someone can help me. If you need more code just ask in the comments section :)

```
Expanded(
                            child: Container(
                                height: 30,
                                width: 295,
                                child: StreamBuilder(
                                    stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                        .collection('texts')
                                        .snapshots(),
                                    builder: (BuildContext context,
                                        AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                                      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                                        return Center(
                                          child: Marquee(
                                              text:
                                                  "Info wird geladen        "),
                                        );
                                      }

                                      return ListView(
                                        children:
                                            snapshot.data!.docs.map((document) {
                                          return Container(
                                            child: Center(
                                                child: Text(document['text1'])),
                                          );
                                        }).toList(),
                                      );
                                    })))
```

Cloud Firestore Snapshot:
[image: Cloud Firestore Snapshot]

Comment: Please add a snapshot of your cloud firestore

Comment: @Josteve edited it!

Comment: Is it the data at `startpage` you want to show in the text?

Comment: Yes, that is the data i want to show..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try: `Text(document['startpage']))` instead of `Text(document['text1'])),`

Comment: You really saved me! Thanks so much!!!

Comment: You are welcome @LucasKnötig